# Vizard fails to load .osgb file

Tags: python, vizard

I'm trying to load a .osgb file in vizard with `viz.addChild('filename.osgb')` but I always get the error

`ERROR: Failed to load model`

I've tried to use the relative path, the absolute path, but to no avail. This is on a Windows machine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. It turns out the .py script that you're running with Vizard needs to be in the same folder as the files you want to load into, with the exception being the models that come with Vizard and are somewhere in the installation folder.